# loop through all comboboxes with specific name

Tags: vb.net

is it possible to loop through all comboboxes with specific name. For example I have 25 comboboxes in a groupbox i need to loop through 20 of them (each of this 20 have name special_combo_1,special_combo_2 and etc. but another 5 have another names so i need to leave as they are)and change their width at once or change the text or anything else.

Comment: yes it is possible.  Create a List(of Combobox) and put the desired controls in it in FormLoad

Comment: please,can you give me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all the controls the `GroupBox` contains.
Then, you should cast each `Control` object to the `ComboBox` type by using [`TryCast(Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx).
You can check the prefix with [`String.StartsWith(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
For Each Item As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
    Dim ComboBoxItem As ComboBox = TryCast(Item, ComboBox)
    If ComboBoxItem IsNot Nothing Then
        If ComboBoxItem.Name.StartsWith("special_combo_") Then
            ' Code here
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: it would work better for the OP as `For Each cbo As ComboBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)` since he may want to refernece cbo-specific props

Comment: As a code-only answer this has been flagged as low-quality and will be probably deleted soon. Please add an explanation about what this code does.

Comment: i have numbers in these comboboxes can I sort the list(ascending) by numbers in end of name(special_combo_1 after special_combo_2 and etc.?

Comment: @Daniel_M This is another question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `OfType` to make a collection of comboboxes from the control collection. No `TryCast` needed so increase in preformance. Then filter them with the `Where` clause to drill it down even further. Now you iterate only a small collection of controls.

```
Dim spComboboxes = 
    GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Combobox)().
    Where(Function(cb) cb.Name.StartsWith("special_combo_")).ToList()
```

Iterate the comboboxes:

```
For Each cb In spComboboxes
  'do something
Next
```

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Then you should look up how to recursively get the controls. If you have trouble implementing that, then you should start a new question.

Comment: Its not my question, I know how to do this already. It was a response to his answer... it seems someone didnt read the whole thread.